# Problem activating TargetDisplay Mode for Mac Mini (2014) connected to iMac 21'' (mid-2010)

Tags: imac, mac-mini, target-display

I'm trying to use iMac 21''(mid-2010, Mavericks) as a display for newly purchased Mac Mini (late 2014) and I'm unable to activate TargetDisplay Mode. The devices are connected using MiniDisplay Cable and pressing Command-F2 or Command-Fn-F2 does nothing (tried in when logged off as well), the screen doesn't even blink.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the Mid-2010 iMac 21" doesn't support Target Display mode. Only the 27" iMac from that generation does, which is why you are getting no response when you press CMD+F2. The Apple website offers more information [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204592): [image]

Comment: Hmm, why does it [iMac] have DisplayPort then? To add another display?

Comment: Yep, that's the reason.